# How to make current parent Business unit to child BU without breaking existing functionality and integrations?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a Marketing cloud org that have only one BU and that is connected with SF Production environment, Now we want to make this as a Child and want to create a new parent BU so can we do this without breaking the functionality like the existing journey, automation, integartion etc?

Comment: YOu can't make the EID a child, You would need to create a new BU and migrate everything there

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve is not possible. EID is the only Business Unit which can't have it's hierarchy changed. It will always be the root of the BU tree structure. This is exactly why I always recommend to start with at least two business units:

1. EID: This should purely be used for admin purposes and handle data integrations, distributing the "inbound" data to child business units utilising a.o. shared data extensions. No marketing operations should be handled here.
2. Child BU X: This will represent your market, brand, or however you manage your digital marketing organisation. Here you will build your assets, journeys, and hold contacts/subscribers who have a relationship with this particular BU.

When you come to a point, where you want to enable a new market or brand, you will purchase and create it as a new sibling to BU X. You will replicate the data model from BU X, and ensure the appropriate filtering of data into each of these BUs. Do keep in mind, you don't need Multi Org connector, if connecting a single SF Org with multiple MC BUs.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I will use same BU as a parent and will create the 5-6 BU as a child then what will be the pros and cons for doing this as in my requirement I have to make this as a Child BU but due to lots for work to move in child BU I am thinking to keep this as it is and I am thinking to add the other BU as its child. It should be on same level as a child but as we cant do this then I need to know about pros and cons. Thanks in Advance

Comment: @RavikantKedia -this is a question with no simple answers. It is a key discussion points when designing a solution architecture for a Marketing Cloud implementation. It depends highly on the integrations, requirements for data separation, etc. I will strongly suggest migrating everything to child BU and leaving the ENT BU for integrations only.

Comment: yes but we have approx. 260 journey, 160 automation, lots of cloud pages, integration etc. so I don't think it is simple to just migrate everything on child BU as it will take a good amount of time may be 4-5 months, could you suggest any other solution here?

Comment: can you please let me know the cons are of using the parent BU as it is as  current BU has 5 years worth of campaigns and that have lots of configuration so we are thinking to use same as a parent ?

Comment: can you please let me know the cons are of using the parent BU as it is as current BU has 5 years worth of campaigns and that have lots of configuration so we are thinking to use same as a parent ?